# Perl CAM::PDF splitting words improperly

Tags: perl, pdf

I'm using the CAM::PDF Perl module to parse PDFs.  The module works great except for one issue, it seems to split words randomly.  Is there any way of fixing this via settings or some algorithmic way to put the words back together?

For example:

"has offices located in New Yor k and Dublin."
    -Notice New York

"price competit ion"
    -price competition

The section of code is below:

```
    $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($pdf_name);    
    $text = $pdf->getPageText($page);
    print("$text\n");
```

;

Comment: How are you using the module? Show your code so people who want to help have something to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's not always possible to reconstruct the original text from a PDF. Often the physical structure doesn't match the output.

In this case you are quite possibly being affected by manual kerning. I.e. splitting on character pairs and adjusting the spacing to produce a more pleasing result - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning.

So breaking within words and outputting smaller chunks, which is being recognised by [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CAM%3a%3aPDF) as separate words.

If you have some control on your PDF production, you could experiment with fonts and kerning settings - but this might also compromise output quality.

[PDF::OCR2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDF%3a%3aOCR2) is likely to handle kerning more robustly and might do a better overall job of recognizing the original text.

Comment: Why do you say PDF::OCR2 is more likely to handle kerning more robustly?  I noticed it hasn't been updated in almost 2 years which always makes me worry.

Comment: Just because its working from an image, so may tend to recognise words better.